# Linear or logarithmic LED bar for speaker overload protection

Tags: power, linear, indicator

I have built a 2.1 home cinema audio system. The amplifier modules are severely overpowered for the mid/high speakers I use.

Main reason for this is that the amplifier modules (TDA8954) produce an output with reasonable distortion which is matched to the speakers. The rated output is on a level I do not intend to ever listen at because of the unacceptable distortion at that output level.

To avoid inadvertently putting the volume at too high a level I want to add some LED indicators to indicate when I play at too high an output power.

The easiest implementation is to build something using a LED bar display. Even at lower levels that would give me a nice animation and an idea at which level I am playing.

The question is, should I use a linear LED bar, or logarithmic? I know logarithmic is preferred to display perceived audio level.

If the main reason is speaker protection, I tend to believe that a linear LED bar is the better solution. Taking into account that output power is a quadratic function of output voltage, a logarithmic display would display only small steps for huge variations in delivered power.

The downside of this would be that at lower levels the linear LED bar would not even lit up most of the time. That is fine, and preferred over blowing my speakers.

Comment: your question is asking for an opinion ... such questions are off topic here because every answer is correct

Comment: How long of a clip is acceptable? A short clip may not be visible to your eye. You may need a pulse stretcher.

Comment: I have a feeling that the same parts used to make a LED bar could be applied to an active muting/protection cct with a single LED to indicate you’ve gotten too loud.

Comment: Why are you using an amplifier that has a rated output power that is much too high? What causes the "inacceptable distortion" at that level, your hearing, the speakers or the amplifier? If the amplifier output is clipping which produces severe distortion then why not turn down the volume control like in all audio systems even a low power clock radio.

Comment: linear is easiest as TI is still making LM3914, OTOH there's still thousands of new-old-stock logarythmic LM3915 available and not too egregious scalper prices.

Comment: @jsotola If this is asking for an opinion, so many questions in electronics are. Is asking for "best practice" or "correct design" also an opinion?

Comment: @Mattman944 I am not talking about clipping. I am talking about a warning when output power gets too high. And I know about pulse stretchng. My question was log vs lin display.

Comment: @Brian Yes, I considered that as well. With 2 indicators, pre-warning and warning. That would need 2 comparators. Almost as must as a single LED bar IC. When I choose a LED bar IC I get some visual nicety for free.

Comment: @Audioguru I explained that. The TDA8954 has a reasonable distortion up to 50 Watts, but is capable of 200 Watts. At 10% distortion that is. I don't want to use one of those ubiquitous class D chips which produce 50 Watts at 10% distortion.

Comment: @Jasen I have both the UAA180 (linear) and the LM3915 (log) in stock. Hence my question.

Comment: The datasheet for the TDA8954 shows a graph of typical power of about 110W into 4 ohms per channel with a +/- 41V supply (82V total) with less than 0.1% distortion at low mid and high frequencies. Maybe you have 8 ohm speakers and a lower voltage supply.

Comment: @Audiguru It is not the output power at 0.1% distortion I am worried about. It is the maximum achievable output (even at unacceptable distortion) I am worried about.